# SQLalchemy internals and design pattern

Tags: python, database, design-patterns, database-design, sqlalchemy

What is the design pattern in SQLalchemy and how does it work?

1. I wonder how defining each column as class variable in a child class of db.Model provides necessary information to create table. How does db.create_all get these data?
2. We usually don't explicitly define **init** for the table, however we can use the initializer. How this is done?
3. Why this design has been used? Is it because class variables are initiated when the interpreter reaches the definition, while there can be many instances?
4. Just to understand the internals, let's assume we replace SQL backend with a dictionary. What would be minimal code to simulate SQLalchemy wrt table definition and create_all?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the source code for sqlalchemy? https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy. If you want to know how something works take a look at the code.

Comment: No, it is too big and not clear where to start.

Comment: (1) [Metadata](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/metadata.html) (2) The `__init__` method can be defined in [orm.declarative_base](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/mapping_api.html?highlight=declarative_base#sqlalchemy.orm.declarative_base.params.constructor), otherwise the [default](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/5677ea7f1b8de3cba5c8c0fbf70e3840a5a9889f/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/decl_base.py#L1139) is used. (3) Columns are [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).

Comment: This question is probably more suited towards the SQLalchemy community because it involves library design decisions. It's great to dig in and understand the thought process behind why a library is the way it is (you will learn a lot in doing so). But most people here on SO will not know any of this without doing the same amount of research you will have to do to find the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say you want to look at the SQLAlchemy chapter in ["The Architecture of Open Source Applications"](https://www.aosabook.org/en/sqlalchemy.html), particularly the section "Classical vs. Declarative".

> The Declarative extension uses a Python metaclass, which is a handy way to run a series of operations each time a new class is first declared, to generate a new Table object from what's been declared, and to pass it to the mapper function along with the class. The mapper function then does its job in exactly the same way, patching its own attributes onto the class, in this case towards the id attribute, and replacing what was there previously.

I've seen this referred to as declarative metaclass programming. If you're looking for a more gentle example, then "Pro python" by Marty Alchin has a much simpler example of this pattern mapping columns in a csv file to a class, [someone has helpfully put just the code up on github](https://github.com/pannkotsky/sheets) although the book has a much fuller explanation of what's going on.

I will add this comment from an old IBM article on python metaprogramming.

> [Metaclasses are deeper magic than 99% of users should ever worry about. If you wonder whether you need them, you don't (the people who actually need them know with certainty that they need them, and don't need an explanation about why). -- Python Guru Tim Peters](https://web.archive.org/web/20120627014539/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-pymeta/index.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I will read more about meta programming.